# Use of article the

Tags: definite-article

Insert the necessary article:

> Where did you buy umbrella?

For this The book has answered

> Where did you buy *the* umbrella?

Is it correct to use *the* instead of *an*, and, if so, then why?

Comment: Interestingly, you wrote *the book* in your question, not *a book*. It's exactly the same use of *a/the* as in your example sentence.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, *the* is the correct article, because the umbrella has already been bought. Therefore, it's assumed we are talking about a particular umbrella – namely, the umbrella you bought and now own.

Interestingly enough, if you didn't have an umbrella, and you were asking me where you could buy one, the article would be different:

> Where can I buy *an* umbrella?

But if I'm asking you where you got your umbrella, I use a definite article:

> Where did you buy *the* umbrella?

or I could use a determiner:

> Where did you buy *that* umbrella?

---

I'm guessing you were confused because the umbrella has not already been mentioned. The "already been mentioned" guidance for when to use *the* is just a rule of thumb with  plenty of exceptions. There are many ways to allude to a particular item without mentioning it verbally. And there are many other uses for the definate article, too, such as when we want to make a "generalized reference" to something. That's why I would say to you:

> I heard you play *the* piano.

and not:

> I heard you play *a* piano.

Comment: As  definite article rules says the is used before musical instruments,thanks man

Comment: Well, you can use _a_ before a musical instrument, too: _Who left a clarinet on the floor over there?_

Comment: "Playing a violin" would only be suitable if the
speaker is describing a scene, and only wants to
convey the physical presence of the instrument
itself.
"Playing the violin," rather, carries with it the
connotation of the act or skill of playing the
instrument. I copied this from some site